# Can I add horizontal scroll bar for nav bar? how?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, responsive

I'm new to html/css and javascript. I want Buttons to be on the same line and they can be scrolled through horizontally... The problem is two

1. I can't get them all in one line rather some are going to second line..
2. I can't understand how can I have them all in one so I can scroll them horizontally...

As attached images I want these circles to be on same line... What I have done is given below. But the problem is some of these circles are shown in next line...
My code is Below
Html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Areeba Textile</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Unstitch Cloth</h1>
        <p>Category of Unstitch Cloth available</p>
        <div class="topnav circontain">
            <a href="" >Silk</a>
            <a href="">Cotton</a> 
            <a href="">Lawn</a>
            <a href="">Khadder</a>
            <a href="">Linen</a>
            <a href="">Shafoon</a>   
            <a href="">Chiffon</a>
            <a href="">1 piece</a>
            <a href="">2 piece</a>
            <a href="">3 piece</a>
            <a href="">Winter</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sriracha&display=swap");

body {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #585858;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Yaldevi', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, p, h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.circontain a{
    color: black;
    display: inline;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 200px;
    background-color: pink;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 18px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer; 
} 
.topnav {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: 150px;

  } 
.topnav a{
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  
  /* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5) ;
    color: black
  }
  
  /* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    color: rgb(15, 13, 13,0.5);
  }
```

I want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz01a.png) or [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4455o.png)  so that I can scroll horizontally...

Lastly, Advanced Thankyou for help!

Comment: [`div.topnav.circontain { overflow-x: auto; }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) Having said that, horizontal scrolling is something that you should always strive to avoid in a web page and instead use CSS Media Queries to alter the layout when the ViewPort isn't wide enough to show the content.

Comment: I see. Thank You... can we style these scrollbar though?

Comment: You can but it's browser specific, not standard.

Answer (score 0):

use -webit-box example:

```
body {
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 color: #585858;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Yaldevi', sans-serif;
 margin-top: 30px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}


 h1, p, h3 {
  text-align: center;
   color: black;
 }
 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.circontain a{
  color: black;
  /* display: inline; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  /* line-height: 200px; */ 
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 18px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer; 
} 
.topnav {
  height: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow: auto;

 } 
 .topnav a{
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
 }

 /* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5) ;
  color: black
 }

 /* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: rgb(15, 13, 13,0.5);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also take help from this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport"   content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#support">Support</a>
  <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
  <a href="#tools">Tools</a>  
  <a href="#base">Base</a>
  <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
  <a href="#more">More</a>
  <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
  <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
  <a href="#people">People</a>
  <a href="#work">Work</a>
</div>

<h2>Horizontal Scrollable Menu</h2>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the    effect.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a simple nav bar with horizontal scroll you can add item according to your need

Comment: I've added items as per my needs but showing vertical scroll instead of horizontal scroll bar.... I have at least 11 a elements. I don't know what wrong thing I'm doing... I used the same code as you provided... only items are as per my needs...

Comment: Please connect me on my mail id and lets sort it there

Comment: yash21011999@gmail.com my mail id

Answer (score -1):

You can make overflow auto and scroll behaviour to the topnav or the navigation.

Comment: Yes, but how???

Comment: I've tried making overflow auto but its show vertical scroll bar and the issue still persist; the issue of keeping all circles in one line... is there another technique?

Comment: Make display flex and flex direction horizontal or the other way is after making overflow auto set its scroll behaviour to horizontal

Comment: Do one thing set display flex to the container containing the circles and then set its flex direction horizontal after that you can set their height width whatever required and overflow auto with scroll behaviour horizontal